# How to set up a beamer as in attached file?

Tags: beamer

I wonder if someone know how I can code the same template as shown in the attached file.

1. The color code is easy for me to find but what kind of template do I need to find to get the same design?
2. The bar below contain "week 1" and "banach spaces recap". In my beamer now I have "three" sections. How can I make it just contain as shown?
3. How to make shadows under the blue bar?

I'm not the strongest in these designs in LaTeX. Anyway if someone have a LaTeX code for this beamer or similar, feel free to share.

Thanks in advance.

---

[image]

Comment: You may find the desired template here https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: The theme seems to be Warsaw with a background similar to `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=yellow!25, bottom=green!15]`. About the alignment of footer parts, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Another question is. When I run my TeX code, the footer moves "week 1" to the right and "banach spaces recap" to the left, i.e. the oppositie way as shown in my picture. How can I force footer to be like on the picture?

Comment: And also, I'm looking for the font but it seems that I cannot find it... I've tried a lot of fonts but seems that I cannot find the version on the beamer shown in my picture...